# what kind of data should we have to use classification?

Tags: r, classification, clustering, categorical-data

I don't know which of the classification or clustering should I use for my data.could anyone explain which conditions should exist for implementing each of them(classification , clustering)?In addition I should mention my data has both categorical and continuous variables.
Any little help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In classification, you know what the classes are.  In clustering, you don't know and are trying to discover them.

Comment: For example for the iris data which we do know the number of clusters(setosa,versicolor,virginia) Can't clustering be used?

Comment: It could be, but it's hard to see what the purpose would be, unless you think the species are mislabeled.

Comment: In order to find any new patterns within data through clustering, you need solid domain knowledge. Only then will you be able to dissociate the norm from the unusual. For the iris dataset, you already know the classes, though this does not hinder you to come up with any other number of clusters. It is to you to give each of them a (new) label / meaning then.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your dataset has no class labels, you can resort to unsupervised learning (including clustering) to explore your dataset and group the observations into classes (typically named clusters or groups), which you can then try to label yourself.

Once the "clusters" have been labeled or if the dataset already contains such class labels, you can use your labeled data set to derive the class labels for any new unseen unlabeled data. That's what supervised learning (including classification) is there for.